# Code Deploy Health Constraint Error EC2&GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to launch a single EC2 instance and connect it to my Github utilizing the CodeDeploy service on AWS. I'm having trouble with the actual deployment of a revision to my EC2 instance. It seems that there is something wrong with the recognition of my EC2's health. The EC2 however, is running perfectly, the code deploy agent is running on the instance and the IAM roles are configured appropriately. I've been at this for hours and I cant seem to figure out what is wrong.

[image: Error]

[image: Agent]

[image: EC2 Instance IAM Role]

[image: Code Deployment Service Role]

[image: Trust Relationship for Code Deployment Service Role]

[image: User Data Script for EC2 instance Launch]

Comment: This is a very generic error which most likely has nothing to do with instance health. I've used CodeDeploy with Bitbucket rather than GitHub and ran into similar types of issues. For example, the EC2 instance couldn't pull code from the S3 bucket (where Bitbucket uploads the code) because of a permissions issue. I image GitHub works similarly, that it first uploads your zipped code to S3. Double check that your EC2 is allowed to get that code.

Comment: I got it, it was actually the AppSpec file that needed to be added in the root directory of the source code. But thank you for your response.